# Customer (delivers?) precious metal bullion to the bank

Tags: word-choice

A customer want to place his gold to bank account. He shows up in a bank with his gold bars and says that he wants to put it to his gold account.

I was unable to choose the correct word here.

Customer delivers his precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer leaves his precious metal bullion in the bank.
Customer gives up his precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer leaves out his precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer leaves his precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer submits his precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer puts away precious metal bullion to the bank.
Customer ... precious metal bullion to the bank.

Which word should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deposit**

You make a money or check deposit with the bank, I assume Gold should be no different.

The customer deposits his precious metal bullion with the bank.

Comment: The customer saves his gold into his gold investment account. I am web programmer.

Comment: If it is a Gold Investment account a deposit would be made, and the gold credited to his account.Hence to me, deposit is correct.Am no banker either!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, whenever anything is placed in a bank account, the verb used is "deposit"; eg "The customer deposited his precious metal bullion in the bank account.". Colloquially, you could substitute "bank" for "bank account" and no one would be confused about the meaning. If you are preparing formal documentation, though, you would want to specify that it was deposited in the bank account belonging to the customer.

Alternatively, the verb "secure" could be used; eg "The customer secured his precious metal bullion with the bank" which implies that he likely placed it in an account of some sort, and has done so for the purpose of safekeeping.

If the purpose of the statement is to declare the specific actions taken by the customer for the purposes of record-keeping, use "deposit".

If the purpose of the statement is to imply the reason the customer deposited bullion in his account, use "secure".